# Freelancer.com and Invoices

Tags: freelance-websites, remote, working-from-home

I've recently signed up for Freelancer.com and I'm trying to get how the system works. This is not about Freelancer.com per se but applies to all similar web sites.

Let's say I won a job and successfully complete it. Then,how does the invoicing procedure work? Is Freelancer.com issuing an invoice on behalf of me automatically ? if that is so what kind of information would the invoice contain? Will it  appear as being issued by Freelancer itself, thus the invoice would contain Freelancer's.com business details, or will it appear as being issued by me , thus it would contain my details ?

Or do I somehow have to issue an invoice manually myself?

Comment: I remember that Elance had an option to print an invoice for each milestone or payment. I am not sure about others. Odesk probably has it. So should Freelancer. but you have to ask their support. It's much faster.

Comment: Whether you think it's "not about freelancer.com per se" or not, realize that this is still a web-site support question.